# Alias a Property Name In Powershell 3

Tags: powershell

Using the example below:

```
Get-Service | ConvertTo-HTML -Property Name, Status > C:\services.htm
```

I was wondering if it is possible to alias the property name - the same way you could in SQL:

Example:

```
Get-Service | ConvertTo-HTML -Property Name AS NEWNAME , Status AS MYNEWSTATUSNAME> C:\services.htm
```

I know the above syntax wouldn't work... What is the correct way to alias a property name?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

How about using select-object?

```
get-service | select-object -property @{N='MyNewStatus';E={$_.Status}}, @{N='MyNewName';E={$_.Name}} | ConvertTo-HTML > C:\services.htm
```

Comment: This is a useful answer but the better answer to the question that was ACTUALLY asked is the one given by @mjolinor below:Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty
`code`
dir | % {$_ | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name 'lw' -Value 'LastWriteTime' -PassThru} | sort lw

Comment: Aliasing like this is super useful for piping times into New-Timespan `select @{N='LastWriteTime';E={$_.LastSeen}} | New-TimeSpan | Select Days`

Answer (score 18):

The way to alias a property name is to add an AliasPropery to the object.

```
Get-Service | 
foreach {
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name MYNEWSTATUSNAME -Value Status -PassThru
} |
Select Name,MYNEWSTATUSNAME
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer to the question that was asked.  It doesn't "change" the object" or require what could be a long select to get ALL the other properties.  

This solution simply adds the alias, and Add-Memor -AliasProperty was available in PowerShell 2.0
(Some of us have thousands of Servers, some of them don't have anything more than PowerShell 2.0)

Comment: Nifty! But unless I'm missing something the `foreach` loop is redundant: just `Get-Service | Add-Member ...` should work.

Answer (score 4):

You could do an intermediate step of creating objects with the property names you want using the `new-object` cmdlet.

```
Get-Service | foreach{ new-object PSObject -property @{newname=($_.Name); newstatus=($_.Status)}} | ConvertTo-Html > .\services.htm
```

Comment: This works, too- and worth acknowledging--accepted the above answer, however, for achieving same output without an intermediate step.

Comment: @DudeSolutions I agree Mike's answer is more elegant (and therefore better), but his answer also involves an intermediate step. In fact you could argue it's the same one since his solution does the same thing under the hood. Though I would agree getting rid of the foreach is preferable.

Comment: This is a useful answer but the better answer to the question that was ACTUALLY asked is the one given by @mjolinor below:Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty
`code`
dir | % {$_ | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name 'lw' -Value 'LastWriteTime' -PassThru} | sort lw