# Changing an array column name

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have an array that contains `NotePoperties` that needs to be modified. When reading the array I need to do some code to figure out what the correct title for the array column should be.

This code is ready and works fine:

```
$Permissions | Get-Member | ? MemberType -EQ NoteProperty | % {
    $Column = $Permissions.($_.Name)
    $GroupResult = Switch ($Column[1]) {
        'GROUP' {$Settings[0].Group  + ' '}
        ''      {break}
        Default {$group + ' '}
    }
    $SiteResult = Switch ($Column[0]) {
        'Site'  {$Settings[0].Code + ' '}
        ''      {break}
        Default {$site + ' '}
    }
    $Result = ($GroupResult + $SiteResult + $_.Name).Trim()
}
```

What I'm now trying to do is update/modify the existing title with the generated `$Result` string from above:

```
$_.Name = $Result
```

When doing this, PowerShell throws the error `'Name' is a ReadOnly property.`.

What is the best way of changing the title of the array? I also need to remove line 2 and line 3, but I can do that afterwards.

Example of the `$Permissions` array where I'm trying to updated `Plant manager` to `Belgium Awesome Plant manager`:

```
Plant manager | Sales man | Warehouseman
-------------- ----------  -------------
Site          |           |
Group         | Group     |
Stuff         | Stuff     | Stuff
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alias a Property Name In Powershell 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175439/alias-a-property-name-in-powershell-3)

Comment: I know it seems like over-engineering, but I need to calculate the string that goes into the value for the `NoteProperty`. There's no simpler way in doing this then using the `Switch`. On top of this it needs to be an array, because the script I'm feeding accepts arrays.

Comment: @DarkLite1 - to be clear, you're not changing the column name of the *array*, you're changing the property name of an *object*. Your array simply contains a number of objects. **Arrays:** `$array[index]` - **Objects:** `$object.property`. In your case you need to modify every object in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed that this is over-engineered, however you can modify the object in place.

Assuming your object array is `$permissions`, you can iterate over it, add a member of `$result` with value from property `Plant manager` and then remove the `Plant manager` property:

```
$permissions | % { 
    $_ | add-member "$result" -NotePropertyValue $_."Plant Manager"
    $_.psobject.properties.remove("Plant Manager")
}
```

Comment: Thank you arco444, this was exactly what I was looking for. Regarding over-engineering, the problem is that I can't simplify the process to generate the property name of the object as it's based on lots of variables. So almost every column needs to be calculated an recreated. Thx again for this great solution :)

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use [`Add-Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849879.aspx) to add a new `NoteProperty` with the desired name, and copy the value from the existing one.

That being said, it seems like you're [over-engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering) this quite a bit.

How about a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) instead:

```
$Permissions = $Permissions |Select-Object @{Name="Belgium Awesome Plant Manager"; Expression = {$_.'Plant Manager'} },'Sales man','Warehouseman'
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias, but how do you use your suggestion if you don't know how long the array will be upfront? And you need to calculate the `Name=` part for every header that's of the type `NoteProperty`? Plant Manager is just one example, but there are plenty more and some are with Belgium and others aren't. That's why I need the `Switch` based on the header title.

Answer (score 1):

The ReadOnly attribute of the object property is going to be dictated by the object type.  One way around this is to run the object thorugh `Select *`.  This will change the object type to either a PSSelectedObject or PSCustomObject, depending on your PS version, and the property should lose the ReadOnly attribute in the process:

```
$Permissions | Get-Member | ? MemberType -EQ NoteProperty | Select * |% {
```

Comment: Thank you mjolinor, I tried your suggestion but it seems that it doesn't modify the array. When trying `$_.Name = $Result` I can definitely see that it accepts the new value but after that it's not saved. When saving the whole loop in a test variable it's empty to.

Comment: That's probably a consequence of doing it in the pipeline with $_.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a duplicate value with `Add-Member` you could also create an `AliasProperty`

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name Measurement -Value Length -PassThru | select Measurement
```

Answer (score 0):

```
($json | ConvertTo-csv).replace('"name"','"ServiceAccountName"') | ConvertFrom-csv | ConvertTo-Json
```

`$json` is an existing json array with a column name "name". I convert it to a csv file wherein the first line defines the columns and replace the "name" with "ServiceAccountName" and convert it back from csv to json