# Export-Csv for a variable based on certain conditions

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-4.0

I have a PowerShell variable(say `$a`) which contains the following value.

```
Name        Key       Value
------      ------    ------
Value1      Value1    G
Value2      Value2    G
Value3      Value3    G
```

I want to export the variable `$a` to a CSV file, but without having the Key column in the output CSV file. The output should look like this.

```
Name        Value
------      -------
value1      G
value2      G
value3      G
```

I dont want to export the CSV file first and then work on it to achieve the above output. Is there a way or a perhaps a pipeline option in `Export-Csv` cmdlet that will allow me to export only `Name` and `Value` columns to the output CSV?

Comment: `$a | select Name, Value | epcsv ...`

Comment: That works great @PetSerAl

Comment: I was just wondering if I could alias the Name and Value column to ServerName and Status. Is that possible?
Please bear with me, as I am a newbie to powershell.

Comment: @PetSerAl Like all your comments provides a valid answer. Just wondering why you don't post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PetSerAI already provided you the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784287/export-csv-for-a-variable-in-powershell-based-on-certain-conditions#comment68791362_40784287). To rename the column, you can use *calculated properties*:

```
$a | select @{l='ServerName'; e={$_.Name}}, @{l='Status'; e={$_.Value }} | Export-Csv
```

Comment: Yes Martin. I just figured it out in the below link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175439/alias-a-property-name-in-powershell-3
Thanks for the answer Martin.

Comment: You can use `e='Name'` and `e='Value'` to select a property.

Answer (score 1):

you can exclude column too without have to enumerate all your column

```
$a | select -ExcludeProperty Key | Export-Csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```